# What does "it" in "how it" refer to?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix Revolutions* (2003), Seraph along with Morpheus and Trinity meets Merovingian:

> Seraph: You know why we are here?
>
> Merovingian: Come now, what kind of question is this? Of course I
> know. It is my business to know. Some might think this is a strange
> coincidence, but I do not. I am curious, though, as to how **it**
> actually happened.

What does "it" in "how it" refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trio are there to rescue Neo from Mobil Avenue, where his disembodied spirit has somehow been captured by the Merovingian's agent, The Trainman.

The "***it***" in this conversation refers to how Neo seemingly became disconnected from his human body. This is something that the Merovingian apparently hasn't seen before, and is understandably curious about.

> **Trinity:** *Do you know **what happened to Neo?***
>
> **Oracle:** *Yes. **He’s trapped in a place between this world and the machine world.** The link is controlled by a program called the
> Trainman. He uses it to smuggle programs in and out of the Matrix. If
> he finds out where Neo is before you get to him, then I’m afraid our
> choices are going to become difficult.*